# iterate over only two keys of python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the pythonic way to iterate over a dictionary with a setup like this:

```
dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 4, 5], 'c': 6}
```

if I only wanted to iterate a for loop over all the values in `a` and `b` and skip `c`.  There's obviously a million ways to solve this but I'd prefer to avoid something like:

```
for each in dict['a']:
    # do something
    pass
for each in dict['b']:
    # do something
    pass
```

of something destructive like:

```
 del dict['c']
 for k,v in dict.iteritems():
     pass
```

Comment: check if the value is iterable?

Comment: i was hoping someone had a clever trick for this sort of problem

Comment: how could it be more clever?

Comment: is `c` always going to be a string? is that the reason why you want `c` skipped?

Comment: `keys_for_iterables = [k for k in dict if hasattr(d[k], '__iter__')]`. Or put it into a try-block and act as if every value is iterable.

Comment: maybe [item for value in dict.values() for item in value if type(value) == list] though that seems pretty hard to read

Comment: If you always know the two keys you are interested, why not `for each in dict['key1']+dict['key2']`

Comment: Will it always be dict with three pairs or is this meant to be a more general question - "How do I iterate through a subset of a dictionary?" If you really need to just iterate through the values associated with 'a' and 'b' your code will be more clear if access your dictionary with 'a' and 'b' explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more generic way is using filter-like approaches by putting an `if` in the end of a generator expression.

If you want to iterate over every iterable value, filter with `hasattr`:

```
for key in (k for k in dict if hasattr(dict[k], '__iter__')):
    for item in dict[key]:
        print(item)
```

If you want to exclude some keys, use a "not in" filter:

```
invalid = set(['c', 'd'])
for key in (k for k in dict if key not in invalid):
    ....
```

If you want to select only specific keys, use a "in" filter:

```
valid = set(['a', 'b'])
for key in (k for k in dict if key in valid):
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from the `itertools` module to do this:

```
In [29]: from itertools import chain

In [30]: mydict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 4, 5], 'c': 6}

In [31]: for item in chain(mydict['a'], mydict['b']):
    ...:     print(item)
    ...:         
1
2
3
3
4
5
```

To iterate over only the values the keys' value in the dictionary that are instance of `list` simply use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
wanted_key = ['a', 'b']        
for item in chain.from_iterable(mydict[key] for key in wanted_key if isinstance(mydict[key], list)):
    #  do something with the item
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to SSDMS's solution you can also just do:

`mydict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 4, 5], 'c': 6}
for each in mydict['a']+mydict['b']:
    ....`